# fgetcsv does not split at specified delimiter

Tags: php, csv

The following code

```
$fh = fopen('test_import.csv', "r");
$header = fgetcsv($fh,$delimiter=';',$enclosure='"'); //skip headers
print_r($header);
$line = fgetcsv($fh,$delimiter=';',$enclosure='"');
print_r($line);
```

when fed with a file containing this:

```
A;B;C;D;E;F
A;"B";C;"D";E;F
```

returns the following:

> Array ( [0] => A;B;C;D;E;F ) Array ( [0] => A; [1] => B [2] => ;C; [3]
>   => D [4] => ;E;F )

I'm totally puzzled why some of the ; are not recognized properly.

Comment: remove `enclosure='"'` should do it

Comment: The docs are always the best answer http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Thanks,I didn't write the documents I just read them. It didn't mention a bug with the feature enclosure.

Comment: I've added a bug report to php.net https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71226

Comment: It isnt a bug, you dont have the correct amount of parameters

Answer (score -1):

You are missing $length, second parameter:

```
$line = fgetcsv($fh,$length=0,$delimiter=';',$enclosure='"');
```

See PHP documentation: http://php.net/fgetcsv

Comment: From the documents: "Length Must be greater than the longest line (in characters) to be found in the CSV file (allowing for trailing line-end characters). It became optional in PHP 5. Omitting this parameter (or setting it to 0 in PHP 5.1.0 and later) the maximum line length is not limited, which is slightly slower." I'm not interested in length.

Comment: But the parameter is required to use the enclosure properly

Comment: From the documents: '5.1.0 The length is now optional. Default is 0, meaning no length limit.' Anyway, specifiying a length did not change a thing